# Parent divs not appearing when height:auto

Tags: css, html

I have two parent divs, contenttop and contentbottom. I've set both to width:100% and height:auto (I want them to be fluid based on the divs they contain)
In each of those two divs I have two more divs:

```
#col1, #col2, #col3, #col4
{
    position:relative;
    width:45.5%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 3%;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Which are set to be fluid also, i.e., set to the size of whatever text in in them.

The problem I'm having is that the contenttop and contentbottom divs are not showing unless I set a specific height. The #col divs are *behaving* correctly, but the background-color of my content divs don't appear.

What's happening here? And is there a solution?

Here's the full css:

```
body
{
    background-color:aquamarine;
}

p, p.maintextcontent, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#contenttop
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:brown;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#col1, #col2
{
    position:relative;
    width:45.5%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 3%;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#contentbottom
{
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#col3, #col4
{
    position:relative;
    width:45.5%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 3%;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If not a fiddle, then at least the html.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used jsfiddle before, do I just send the link like so? http://jsfiddle.net/DU8aZ/

Comment: Yes! jsfiddle is very handy! Thanks for helping me discover it and thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

That is because the content (#col1 etc.) is floating. These keeps the containers from having a height. One common solution is to add this rule to your containers (#contenttop, #contentbottom):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Check out this simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2DrF/